What is the name given to the table layer in QGIS?
What name is given to this selected layer? It's not a vector layer where you can add geometries, it's something like a table or spreadsheet.


The layer_styles table is used for saving the QGIS styles into a database (for example GeoPackage). The table is hidden when GeoPackage data is added if the "Show system and internal tables" option is not selected.

The table has these fields

Users are not supposed to edit the layer_styles table directly. QGIS is dealing with it internally when styles are stored into a database https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#save-in-database.

Is it possible to create other tables like these? How do I do that?

Sure. For example by importing CSV file with an option "No geometry (attribute only data)" https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html. Or by reading a non-spatial table from a database. Or by creating a new layer and setting the geometry type into "No Geometry".
